# Juju cannot retrieve charm

Tags: dns, juju

After successfully bootstrapping Juju control node, made sure that DNS is set-up "properly",

```
- I have forwarder name servers at MAAS, 

- resolv.conf at deployed Juju control node is set-up by MAAS to point to MAAS IP

# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 135.XXX.YYY.206
search maas

- control node can resolve outside entities, abnd so by going through MAAS node

ubuntu@huron13:/var$ dig api.jujucharms.com
```

```
; > DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu > api.jujucharms.com

ANSWER SECTION:
api.jujucharms.com.     461     IN      A       162.213.33.121



;; Query time: 35 msec
;; SERVER: 135.XXX.YYY.206#53(135.111.102.206)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 28 22:35:33 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 274
```

```
I still get failure when trying to deploy a bundle


administrator@maas:~/.juju$ juju deploy ./bundle.yaml --debug
17:36:48 INFO  juju.cmd supercommand.go:56 running juju [2.3.5 gc go1.8]
17:36:48 DEBUG juju.cmd supercommand.go:57   args: []string{"juju", "deploy", "./bundle.yaml", "--debug"}
17:36:48 INFO  juju.juju api.go:67 connecting to API addresses: [135.111.102.212:17070]
17:36:48 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:843 successfully dialed "wss://135.111.102.212:17070/model/7d19f49b-561d-4d64-84df-bf49d0049b0f/api"
17:36:48 INFO  juju.api apiclient.go:597 connection established to "wss://135.111.102.212:17070/model/7d19f49b-561d-4d64-84df-bf49d0049b0f/api"
17:36:48 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.application bundle.go:241 model: 
.
.
.
Executing changes:
- upload charm cs:ceph-mon-23 for series xenial
17:36:51 DEBUG httpbakery client.go:244 client do GET https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/xenial/ceph-mon-23/meta/any?include=id&include=supported-series&include=published {
17:36:52 DEBUG httpbakery client.go:246 } -> error 
17:36:52 DEBUG juju.api monitor.go:35 RPC connection died
ERROR cannot deploy bundle: cannot add charm "cs:ceph-mon-23": cannot retrieve charm "cs:ceph-mon-23": cannot get archive: Get https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/ceph-mon-23/archive?channel=stable: proxyconnect tcp: EOF
17:36:52 DEBUG cmd supercommand.go:459 error stack:
cannot retrieve charm "cs:ceph-mon-23": cannot get archive: Get https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/ceph-mon-23/archive?channel=stable: proxyconnect tcp: EOF
```

Any ideas what is that I am missing, and/or how to troubleshoot this are appreciated

Juju version 2.3.5 
MAAS version: 2.3.1 (6470-g036d646-0ubuntu1~16.04.1) 
<\pre>

Answer (score 0):

Resolved,
All proxies were set, with "appropriate" scheme" in front

```
http_proxy=http://135.245.48.34:8000/
https_proxy=https://135.245.48.34:8000/
```

What "works" (at least with this proxy) is having "http" scheme for all

```
http_proxy=http://135.245.48.34:8000/
https_proxy=http://135.245.48.34:8000/
```